# Stack Overflow Error, m-ary tree size

Tags: java, recursion, tree, stack-overflow

What's wrong with my recursion logic?

I'm trying to find the size of an m-ary tree. An MTree Node's children is represented by an ArrayList I implemented. My logic was to have a `for` loop as big as `m` so I could check every child.

```
public AnyType element;
public int m; // MTreeNode will have m children at most
public static ArrayList<MTreeNode> children;


public MTreeNode(AnyType element, int m, ArrayList<MTreeNode> children){
  this.element = element;
  this.m = m;
  this.children = children;

public static int size(MTreeNode<?> t){
  int nodes = 0;

  if(t == null)
     return 0;

  else{
     for(int i = 0; i < t.m; i++){
        size(t.children.get(i));
     }
     return 1 + nodes;
  }
}
```

I'm getting my error at

```
size(t.children.get(i));
```

Comment: 1. This code doesn't compile. 2. How do you call this code (where's the `main()`?

Comment: I had too much code to include all of it. I was wondering if anyone could tell what's wrong with the recursion logic from looking at it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: You probably have a loop in your data structure and it's not a tree